# How to update shared variable in seperate process in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement parallelism using python.

I'm using VS 2017 with python version 3.7.

My code as below:

```
def do_parallelization(self, link_list):
    cpus = multi.cpu_count()
    workers = []
    page_bins = self.__get_chunks(cpus, link_list)

    array_s = Array(c_wchar_p,3)
    for cpu in range(cpus):
    #sys.stdout.write("CPU " + str(cpu) + "\n")
    # Process that will send corresponding list of pages 
    # to the function perform_extractionpage_bins[cpu]
        try:
            worker = multi.Process(name=str(cpu), target= self.get_page_content_para, args=(page_bins[cpu], array_s))
            worker.daemon = True
            workers.append(worker)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()
    print (array_s[:])


def get_page_content_para(self, link_list, array_s):
    array_s[:] = ["up", "down", "left"]
```

In here I'm trying to update `Array` but at the end of calling function, I print the array it gives me below output:

```
["","",""]
```

I have searched in internet but all are saying it should update the variable.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You need a `manager` object. See the **Server process** section of [Sharing State between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the multiprocessing documentation.

Comment: i have tried , . but no chance , thi method is inside a class , is that affect to the process?

Comment: It could, but it's hard to say without a MCVE. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I can get expexted result when i put

```
worker.start()
worker.join()
```

under the

```
worker = multi.Process(name=str(cpu), target= self.get_page_content_para, args=(page_bins[cpu], array_s))
```

but when i put as mentioned is that truly doing parallelism ?

as i understand when is rewrite as mentioned it is executing one by one manner , i mean one process start , end it and then second process is started .

is this parallelism ?

can anyone explain this?